# Javascript Incorrect header check decompressing zlib buffer generated by Python

Tags: javascript, python

I am compressing a string in Python and trying to decompress it in JavaScript.

Compress a string in Python:

```
import zlib, base64

text = "Test string"
result = base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(text.encode("utf-8"))
```

In JavaScript:

```
const zlib = require('zlib');

var data = atob(<text encoded in base64 from Python>);
zlib.inflate(data, function(err, buffer){
    if(!err){
        // doing something
    }
    else{
       console.log(err); // <-- Error: data error: incorrect header check
    }
});
```

In JavaScript, it returns "Incorrect header check" error. How should I compress the data in Python to obtain the same value of zlib.inflate() in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string to `zlib.inflate` in your javascript code, but it expects a `Buffer` instance.

```
var data = Buffer.from('eJwLSS0uUSguKcrMSwcAGWAEWA==', 'base64')

zlib.inflate(data, function(err, buffer) { 
    if (!err) {
       console.log(buffer.toString()); 
    } else {
       console.log(err); 
    } 
})

Test string
```